# Override NativeQuery at Runtime

Tags: jpa, derby

I am using OpenJPA with SqlServer in my project and I have a need to use native SqlServer syntax for a particular query. For this, I have been using the NativeQuery annotation with great results.

However, the issue comes when I need to run a unit test with Derby as my database. As it turns out, Derby does not support the exact syntax of my NativeQuery. My thought is to swap out the NativeQuery with a "Derbified" version to run the test. However, I have not been able to find a way to do this.

Is there any way to override or redefine a NativeQuery for an entity at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

I would use *persistence.xml* to define two `peristence-unit` elements (one for SqlServer and another for Derby) with dedicated *orm.xml* containing `named-native-query`.

persistence.xml

```xml
<persistence version="2.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="sqlserver-pu">
        <mapping-file>META-INF/orm-sqlserver.xml</mapping-file>
        ...
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="derby-pu">
        <mapping-file>META-INF/orm-derby.xml</mapping-file>
        ...
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

orm-sqlserver.xml

```xml
<entity-mappings version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd">

    <named-native-query name="findFirst" result-class="com.tyler.example.order">
        <query>SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Order</query>
    </named-native-query>
</entity-mappings>
```

orm-derby.xml

```xml
<entity-mappings version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd">

    <named-native-query name="findFirst" result-class="com.tyler.example.order">
        <query>SELECT * FROM Order FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY</query>
    </named-native-query>
</entity-mappings>
```

With such an approach you have improved interoperability of your code as entities (portable across databases) are decoupled from queries (vendor specific). All you need is to select a proper persistence unit at runtime and execute a given query (they must have the same name).

Another approach that comes into my mind is to define a named native query twice for each entity using `@NamedNativeQuery` annotation with different `name` and `query` attributes, but at runtime you would then probably need some "ifology" to determine a proper one.